# how to create .repo file without $releasever as

Tags: bash, shell

i would like to create own *.repo file during kickstart for local repo usage
i add this in the PostInstall part. 
The problem i got is, that it uses $releasever & basearch as variable not as string:

```
/bin/cat <<EOF > /user/test.cfg
[lbase]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
EOF
```

how can i disable that i have no blanks in result quote the var ?
(var is not set in kickstart, var is read later during yum update)

```
[lbase]
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos//os/
........
[updates]
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos//updates//
```

i need some like

```
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch
```

in my *.repo file.......

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want variables to be expanded in a here-doc, put the identifier in quotes.

```
/bin/cat <<'EOF' > /user/test.cfg
[lbase]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mirror/repo/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
EOF
```